# How to interpret inequalities between morphisms in a categorical setting

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I am working on some categories over **Prost**, the category of partially ordered sets with order-preserving maps as morphisms. Everything goes smoothly, but at some point I need the property $f \leqslant g$, where $f,g: P \to Q$ are two morphisms of **Prost**.
This is of course defined by $f(x) \leqslant g(x)$ for all $x \in P$, but I wonder whether there is a more categorical definition. In which direction should I look at: enriched categories, something else? References would be welcome.

Comment: The category of posets can be regarded as a poset-enriched category, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a natural transformation when you regard posets as categories and order-preserving maps as functors.